# How do I add custom contextual links in a block?

Tags: 8

I want to add more contextual links (e.g. "Edit Block") to my block apart from the existing "Configure Block".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The existing answer is 7.x code. I haven't tried it yet, but based on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block_content%21src%21BlockContentViewBuilder.php/function/BlockContentViewBuilder%3A%3AalterBuild/8.2.x, you simply have to put something like that in $build return by your block plugin. Or alter it in

Answer (score 2):

I know that this blog post is 100 years old, but it still applies:

http://bleen.net/blog/easier-way-add-contextual-links-drupal-7

The basic idea is to make use of `hook_contextual_links_view_alter`

For example:

```
function MYMODULE_contextual_links_view_alter(&$element, &$items) {
  // This hook is called for EVERY set of contextual links
  // on a page.  We first want to check the $element to make
  // sure we are adding a link to the correct list of contextual
  // links. In this case we only want to add a link to blocks
  // created by the "search" module. We just add links using the
  // same array structure as is used by theme_links.
  if (isset($element['#element']['#block']) && $element['#element']['#block']->delta == "site_tweets-site_tweets_block") {
    $element['#links']['social-networks'] = array(
      'title' => 'Edit social network links',
      'href' => url('/admin/config/system/site-information', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try not to post link only answers, as links can go down over time. Better is to include the essential part of the answer here and provide a link for further reference. Could you edit your post?

Comment: Also note that OP is referring to the [Quick Edit api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!quickedit!quickedit.api.php/function/hook_quickedit_editor_alter/8.2.x) specifically, for which there is hardly any documentation at all except for Doxygen.